# After sorting initially with time and listing_url, why cant I do the same again?

Tags: javascript, meteor, underscore.js, atmosphere

Below code sorts the field with `time` and `listing_url` The problem is once I do sorting with `time`, I am unable to sort it with `listing_url`.

Also once if I sort it with `listing_url`, i cant really sort it again. I feel like there is some problem with sessions but I got no idea what to do.

Can somebody add a session delete o unset function into my code ?

TIA

```
Template.listItem.helpers({
entry :function() {

var selector={};
var options={
  sort:{}
};

var sort_by_time = Session.get('sort_by_time');

var sort_by_listing = Session.get('sort_by_listing');

console.log('sort_by_time:', sort_by_time);
console.log('sort_by_listing:',sort_by_listing);

    Session.unset('sort_by_listing');


if (sort_by_time) {
  options.sort[sort_by_time] = -1;
};

Session.unset('sort_by_time');


if (sort_by_listing) {
    options.sort[sort_by_listing] = 1;
};


console.log('Selector:',selector);
console.log('Options',options);

var facebookposts=FacebookPost.find(selector,options);
  return facebookposts;
  session
}
})
```

Comment: Unrelated, but why do you have `;` after your `if` blocks? It's harmless, but unnecessary. Blocks are self-terminating, you don't put a statement terminator after them.

Comment: but at the end, there should be a `;` because it is a statement!

Comment: Where is your code that does the sorting?  Where is your code that sets options.sort[sort_by_time] to 1 and options.sort[sort_by_listing] to -1?

Comment: Probably your code could be improved, but I would guess that's not your real problem. I think your problem is the way you are using your time field. If you sort by time, which is indivisible, then any other sorting on a second level cannot work. However if you sort first by day or maybe hour, for example, then sorting on a second level by listing_url can work.

Comment: To unset, just do Session.set('sort_by_listing', null);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mark Leiber thanks I figured that out!
This works like a charm

```
Template.listItem.helpers({
```

entry :function() {

```
var selector={};
var options={
  sort:{}
};

var sort = Session.get('sort');

if(sort) {
    if(sort == 'created_at')
        options.sort[sort] = -1;

    if(sort == 'listing_url')
        options.sort[sort] = 1;
}

console.log('Selector:',selector);
console.log('Options',options);

var facebookposts=FacebookPost.find(selector,options);
  return facebookposts;
```

}
})